# Creation of event in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Can any one help me how to create an event in MySQL so that it has to be executed for every 10 seconds?

I have tried with the following code but it is inserting only once but when i see whether the event is running of not in process list it is in running state

```
   create event e_insert on schedule at 'timestamp' + interval 1 second do insert into 'table_name' values (now());
```

Comment: MySQL is not a place for timed events. Set it in your server side codes / cron job instead.

Comment: @Shivan Raptor Why not events?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: We have events in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write -

```
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '10' SECOND
```

instead of `on schedule at...`

[Using the Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html).

**Edit:**

```
CREATE EVENT event1
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY '10' SECOND
  STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
  DO 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO...
END
```

Comment: Even after following your syntax the insert statement is executed for only once .

Comment: sir here i have got syntax to use **AT**  (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)

Comment: Here is the syntax for event creation  `CREATE EVENT e_insert ON SCHEDULE at '2012-10-08 16:40' + interval 1 second DO INSERT INTO event_test values (now());`

Comment: Here is the syntax for table creation 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `testing`.`event_test`;
CREATE TABLE  `testing`.`event_test` (
  `current_date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`current_date_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;'

Comment: Try to add `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE` clause.

Comment: And use 'ON SCHEDULE EVERY', not 'ON SCHEDULE AT'!

Comment: You can create and edit events easily with visual object editor in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (free express version). There is a good editor for event object.

Comment: Sir even after adding 'ON COMPLETION PRESERVE' clause it is inserting the data for only once.

Comment: Sir if i use ON SCHEDULE EVERY iam getting the following error message **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON COMPLETION PRESERVE DO INSERT INTO event_test values (now())' at line 1**

Comment: Thanx for your valuable help sir ill try to do this in doForge studio

Answer (score 0):

set global event_scheduler = 1;

check this [here](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/mysql-events.html)

Comment: Yes i have enabled event_scheduler i have verified in the processlist

Comment: which version of mysql you are using according to the given link those were from MySQL version 5.1